# how to select rows with sum of group in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

Let say I have data in sqlite3 like this:

```
|saleID|data|
|1|a|
|1|b|
|1|c|
|2|x|
|2|y|
|3|t|
|4|x|
|4|y|
```

I want to count how many times saleID in table appear.
How the sql syntax in sqlite to get result like this?

```
|saleID|count|
|1|3|
|2|2|
|3|1|
|4|2|
```

Thanks for coder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select saleID, count(1) as [count]
from sales
group by saleID
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use group by:

```
select saleID,COUNT(data) from Table group by salesID
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT saleID, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY saleID
```